# Set Value of Property When Delete Key is Pressed in PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid, design-surface

I am currently working on a project that hosts WinForms designer. I am using `PropertyGrid` to display manipulate properties of the controls that are dropped on the `DesignSurface`.

I have created `UITypeEditor`'s to modify values of my custom controls properties.

**How can I reset the value of the property to `null` when Delete key is pressed in the `PropertyGrid`.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is handled in the `PropertyDescriptor`.

You override `ResetValue` and `CanResetValue`.

Comment: Thanks this worked .. I had to implement `ComponentDesigner` & `PropertyDescriptor`.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, all you have to do is add the "DefaultValue" attribute to your property and specify that the default value is null.

Example:

```
[DefaultValue(typeof(Image), null)]
public Image MyLittlePicture { get; set; }
```

Comment: Can't check right now .. will check and let you know if that works.